# Server 2008 Cannot Set User Rights

Tags: windows-server-2008, admin-rights

I attempted to do some Win32 stuff in C# 3.5 to get elevated User Rights for a console app. I develop on Visual Studio 2008 SP1/GDR and things work fine when run under the debugger. Things also work fine when I run the console app stand-alone. Things also run fine when I package everything into an MSI and install it on a 2003 server and run the console app.

If I take the same MSI and install it on a 2008 server with UAC enabled, then run the console app, I get messages like this:

```
Unable to set right for the account "DOMAIN\QAUSER": SeCreateGlobalPrivilege
System.UnauthorizedAccessException    Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

I cannot expect my deployment/server admins to do anything with my app other than install it, and they are not going to turn off UAC. There must be some programmatic way to properly set user rights that I can add to the console app - anyone know how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you use "[Global\" prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382954%28VS.85%29.aspx) to the object name in your application and your application will be started inside a Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server session. In the case your program have to enable [SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716%28VS.85%29.aspx) (`SeCreateGlobalPrivilege`) privilege. See [C# – How to enable SeDebugPrivilege?](http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-how-to-enable-sedebugprivilege/) (but use `SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME` instead of `SE_DEBUG_NAME`) or [Manipulate Privileges in Managed Code Reliably, Securely, and Efficiently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163823.aspx) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that UAC is enabled on the 2008 machine and I cannot comment yet on your question to find out.

If so, ensure that in your app.manifest file in VS (under properties), change

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Even if the code is running as an administrator, you have to get by the UAC warning.

Comment: How does the VS setting affect what my deployed app does? I think there should be something that I can programatically set to do what might go in a VS configuration.

Comment: I doubt that your app after deployment will be able to change the way its run. If that is the case, any malicious app could set itself up and we would be back to the wild west days of XP. The VS setting is part of the UAC process and determines on build, what permissions an app needs. It must still be ran (I think) as an admin and after the setting change, you will see that the icon has the UAC shield on it.